# Programmatically Init versus dequeueForReusableIdentifier for table view cells

Tags: swift, tableview

I'm developing an application with using interface builder and I created some cells that receives a viewModel on it init:

```
class ExampleCell {
    var anInternalView: ExampleView
    var anotherInternalView: ExampleView

    init(viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
         anInternalView = ExampleView(viewModel: viewModel)
         anotherInternalView = ExampleView(viewModel: viewModel)
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

On my tableViewCellForRowAt a simply instantiate the cells using ExampleView(viewModel: viewModel).

Some say that its not so good and that I should be using dequeuForReusableIdentifier. But in fact, that method also calls a init the same number of times that using a custom constructor directly. Also, I cannot pass a viewModel on the init.

I didn't found so much material explaining why using the dequeueForReusableIdentifier is so better. Can someone point me the reason for that ?

Comment: Memory impact is the main factor for this. As an example, create 1000 cells the way you are doing it now and compare against dequeReusableCell. Check the memory usage for both cases and you will see exactly why it is used. Why the memory increase? In your example you are creating many instances that go to memory, never deallocated, with deque the cells are reused, the old ones are removed form memory and the new ones take their place, leading to better memory performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to pass the model to the `init` method. Cells get reused over and over for different rows. You need to set the model in `cellForRowAt` after the cell has been created.

Instead of your `init`, add a `applyModel` (or some similar name) method:

```
class ExampleCell {
    var anInternalView: ExampleView
    var anotherInternalView: ExampleView

    apply(viewModel: ExampleViewModel) {
         anInternalView = ExampleView(viewModel: viewModel)
         anotherInternalView = ExampleView(viewModel: viewModel)
         ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in your `cellForRowAt`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Some ID", for: indexPath) as! ExampleCell
cell.apply(viewModel: someModelForIndexPath)
```

---

The key point to remember is that `init` will only be called a small number of times. If, for example, your table view can only show 6 cells at any given time on screen, then only six (maybe seven) cells will ever be created, even if there are thousands of rows in the table view. So `init` will only be called 6 (or 7) times while `cellForRowAt` (and `apply`) can be called many thousands of times as the user scrolls back and forth through all of the rows.

Comment: But the apply will be called the same number of times that the init, no ? that's my question. Because, if I scroll the table for example, the cellForRowAt will be called and then the apply will be called consuming the same amount of memory, or not?

Comment: No, `init` will only be called a small number of times. If, for example, your table view can only show 6 cells at a time on screen, then only six (maybe seven) cells will ever be created, even if there are thousands of rows in the table view. So `init` will only be called 6 (or 7) times while `cellForRowAt` (and `apply`) can be called many thousands of times as the user scrolls back and forth through all of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

(Extending the correct answer of @rmaddy)

Briefly, `init()` consumes memory and `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:for:)` costs processing. Naturally, we prefer to add a little more time of execution than exhaust the few memory available.

In my opinion, using `init` is not a wrong when using only a few cells, because the problem with `dequeueReusableCell` is the reusing. I mean, if you want a new cell when scrolling, the tableView will assign a *presetted* cell with different configuration and we need to reset (or reconfigure) it. So it could be a good idea to have few immutable instances of the cell. But in the other hand, it will be more *healthly* to `deque` when we do not know how many rows will going to have our tableView.